# Removing orphans after replacing parent in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I persist `School` entities to the Datastore with the `PersistenceManager`. A `School` has a one-to-many relationship with `Student`s:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class School implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "school") @Element(dependent = "true") private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
    ...
    @PrimaryKey private String key;

    School(String name, Level level) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        this.level = Objects.requireNonNull(level);
        this.key = name + "_" + level;
    }
    ...
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Student implements Serializable {
    ...
    @PrimaryKey private Key key;

    Student(String name, School school, int grade) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        this.grade = Objects.requireNonNull(grade);
        this.school = Objects.requireNonNull(school);
        key = KeyFactory.createKey(this.school.getKey(), this.getClass().getSimpleName(), name + "_" + grade + "_" + school.getName());
    }
    ...
}
```

Say I persist a `School` with a few `Student`s:

```
School school = new School("foo", Level.MIDDLE);
Student s1 = new Student("A", school, 6);
Student s2 = new Student("B", school, 6);
Student s3 = new Student("C", school, 6);
school.addStudent(s1);
school.addStudent(s2);
school.addStudent(s3);
PMF.get().getPersistenceManager().makePersistent(school);
```

Later,

```
School school = new School("foo", Level.MIDDLE); // Will have the same primary key as the first!
Student s1 = new Student("A", school, 6);
Student s2 = new Student("B", school, 6);
Student s3 = new Student("D", school, 6); // Note the change! C -> D
// Some code that makes s1 and s2 different from their previous state
school.addStudent(s1);
school.addStudent(s2);
school.addStudent(s3);
PMF.get().getPersistenceManager().makePersistent(school);
```

Since the `School` will have the same `PrimaryKey` each time (namely `"foo_middle"`), the second persist operation overwrites the first. There will be only **1** *School foo*.

Fortunately, the updated versions of *Student A* and *Student B* have replaced their old counterparts in the Datastore since their primary key's were equal. However, there will be **4** `Student` entities in the Datastore since *Student C* was **not destroyed**. This inconsistency becomes relevant in one particular view of my application. How can I get rid of this orphaned student most effectively?

Here's what I've tried/considered:

1. Explicitly delete all `School` entities (this operation will [cascade](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships?csw=1#Dependent_Children_and_Cascading_Deletes) and destroy all the `Student`s it has as well) before adding the new set, instead of letting GAE handle the replacement. This is problematic because (1) the cost is higher in terms of read/writes (2) the deletion and re-adding need to be kept independent with the one coming strictly after the other so the new `School`s don't get deleted as well. This can probably be achieved with transactions?
2. Explicitly deleting all the orphaned `Student` by querying for them before persisting the second `School` and checking them against the `school.getStudents()`. This approach has a high cost associated with it and adds lots of complexity.

Another possibility would be designing the objects in such a way that I could query for all `Student`s that were not orphaned. Then I could delete orphans at fixed intervals just for purposes of keeping storage costs low. However, I don't see how to achieve such a result while still maintaining `School`s and `Student`s that replace an old instance when persisted (by having the same primary key).

Answer (score 1):

The reason Student 'C' isn't dying the fact that you are simply overriding foo_middle not destroying it. The way the DB works is when a duplicate ID is found it overrides the existing one. You see this when you add student 'A' and 'B'. The DB doesn't kill any of the originals just replaces the rest of the data (other than the ID). You  have 2 options depending on your use case:

1) If your removing less than half you could add a date added/updated field, after your update you simply do a query for all those who's date is before the current then delete those.

2) If you will removing more than half do an ancestory query then flush all the students.

Comment: Yes, I understand why they aren't being deleted. Your option 2 is identical to my option 1. Your option 1 is a possibility that I'll explore... Unless I'm mistaken, it would entail having a date field in each `Student`, something I find distasteful since I'm **modifying** the definition of a `Student` so that it fits in a DB better.